# Power BI Reporting Server - Portal Administrator Functionality

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

We've just installed the Power BI Reporting Server and we're running it in a trial based scenario.  We cannot figure out how to get the Portal Administrator option to show up under the settings gear, it should be listed as Admin Portal.

Do we need to link into Office 365 to gain access to this functionality?  The documentation we found only references Power BI via the Azure scenario.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-portal

Answer (score 0):

The documentation link provided says that,

"The admin portal is accessible to all users who are Global Admins in Office 365 or have been assigned the Power BI service administrator role."

So I think you are right, I think you need to link it with Office 365 as an Administrator or as a Power BI service Administrator.

I know this is not a Answer but a comment but I do not have the rights to comment right now.